# No margin right on most right block

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of blocks, and I want to order them in a table-like way. The problem is, that because of the margin-right of the last one, they don't really fit in the way I want them to. [See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/QwGV5/). I want to have 4 blocks on one line, how can I achieve that?

CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 500px;
    height: 10000px;
}

.block {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    background-color: #0f0;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: What about increasing the width of your container box to 600px

Comment: even 520px is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new class for the last block in each row (e.g. `.last`) and make `margin-right:0` for that class.

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block last"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block last"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.last { margin-right: 0; }
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QwGV5/7/)

Comment: `!important` should be avoided at all costs. `.block.last` would be enough to make it a more "specific" rule and apply last.

Comment: !important is a blunt tool and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Agreed. Removed it from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `last-child`, a CSS selector, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/QwGV5/1/

```
.block:last-child {margin-right: 0;}
```

For compatibility: http://caniuse.com/css-sel3

Answer (score 0):

```
div:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

But this will only work in IE9+ (maybe 8, can't remember)

Otherwise, put a class on the last one.

Here's an update to your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QwGV5/2/

I think for what you want to do though, you'd actually want it on every 4th div. So you can use `nth-child`

```
.box div:nth-child(4n) {
  margin-right: 0;   
}
```

Eaxmple: http://jsfiddle.net/QwGV5/4/